# How to tell if scheduled subscription is successful in DolphinDB

Tags: scheduled-tasks, subscription, dolphindb

I have subscribed to a stream table via `subscribeTable()`. But why nothing is ingested to the table that I want to apped subscribed data to? How do i tell if my subscription is successful? My subscribed table is supposed to update on a daily basis and the subscription had worked properly the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `getStreamingStat().pubTables` to check the status of published stream tables. If the result contains the *tableName* and *actionName* passed into `subscribeTable()`, your subscription is successful.
2. Use `getStreamingStat().subWorkers` to check the status of the workers of subscriber nodes. You can find the associated subscription topic by *tableName* and *actionName*. (Note that only topics with streams already consumed by its subscribers will be returned.)

If the subscription topic doesn't exist and offset = -1, check if any data is ingested to the subscribed table (*tableName*) after the subscription.

If the subscription topic doesn't exist and new data has indeed been ingested to the subscribed table, check if the data has been filtered by the *filter* parameter.

If the subscription topic exists, check if there's any error information (*lastErrMsg*) on the subscriber nodes.